# Displaying hierarchical data in HTML.DropDownList Helper method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hierarchy

I have a table in database that has a foreign key to itself. While adding product products I want the users to be able to select a category from DropDownList. Right now, I am able to show the result like following ::

---

- **Electronics**
- **MP3 Players**

But, it would be ideal if they are shown like this, since MP3 Player is a child of Electronics :-

- **Electronics**

  - **MP3 Players**

---

**How can I achieve this in a DropDownList ?** My current code for retrieving and displaying is following respectively :-

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ParentCategoryID = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
        return View();
    }
```

CSHTML

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ParentCategoryID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ParentCategoryID)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need optgroups. Unfortunately MVC has no native support for this. So as mentioned in the following post you can write one yourself:

[ASP.Net MVC 3: optgroup support in Html.DropDownListFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688682/asp-net-mvc-3-optgroup-support-in-html-dropdownlistfor)