# how to make optgroup in asp.mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, optgroup

MVC newbie here again!

I have two lists in my controller.

```
IList<Cars> allCars = _repository.GetAll<Cars>();
IList<Bikes> allBikes = _repository.GetAll<Bikes>();

Cars { Id, Name }
Bikes { Id, Name }
```

So, I have this list of class and I want to display a select dropdown list with an optgroup for bikes and cars, something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xNEm9/

thanks!

Comment: @Nicholas: I can't find anything in how to answer link, what am I supposed to be looking at? Thanks.

Comment: my answer was auto changed to a comment. I'll remove the How to Answer link from that comment. Actually I can't edit it - I will the delete the comment. Basically I was pointing you to this question and answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can without additional code but I think somebody worked on it before: [Support for optgroup in dropdownlist .NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc)