# Consuming a Helper code for optgroup functionality in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I don't have the experience of working with Helpers so I am bit stuck in using a code at hand.

My requirement is simple and all I need is optgroup functionality in `DropDownListFor` extension method. While searching, I came across this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4248856/570928) and have copied this as it is in a file named *MyExtensionClass.cs*.

But, I don't know how to use this or call the extension method defined in this. Please tell me how can i use this with my list.

Right now, following is the controller code for a selectlist for which i want to use the extension methods.

```
ViewBag.ParentCategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name");
```

And this is my view code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Product.CategoryId, 
     (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CategoryId, "---Choose Category---", 
       new { @class = "required" })
```

Please help me upgrade this to extension method with optgroup.

Comment: Now [MVC Support For Optgroup In Dropdownlist Check This](http://www.jquery2dotnet.com/2014/01/html5-dropdownlist-optgroup-tag-in-mvc.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We use Serge Zab's helper for optgroup dropdowns. Here is a sample:

**The viewmodel:**

```
public class OurViewModel
{
    public int? TypeId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GroupedSelectListItem> GroupedTypeOptions { get; set; }
}
```

**The controller:**

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
    var model = new OurViewModel
    {
        // fill with initial values
    };
    PutTypeDropDownInto(model);
    return View(model);
}

[NonAction]
private void PutTypeDropDownInto(OurViewModel model)
{
    model.GroupedTypeOptions = _repos.GetTypes()
        .OrderBy(t => t.Category.EnglishName).ThenBy(t => t.EnglishName)
        .Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
        {
            GroupKey = t.Category.RevisionId.ToString(),
            GroupName = t.Category.EnglishName,
            Text = t.EnglishName,
            Value = t.RevisionId.ToString()
        }
    );
}
```

**The view**

```
@Html.DropDownGroupListFor(m => m.TypeId, Model.GroupedTypeOptions, 
    "[Select a type]")
```

Note that you can't use a regular SelectList. You have to use a collection of his GroupedSelectListItem class. Also, our solution doesn't use viewbag. The dropdown list is strongly typed on the viewmodel.

**Update**

To get the html helper to work in your view, the view needs to be able to find it. You can either add a @using directive at the top of the view with your MyExtensionClass.cs namespace, or add the namespace to the view-specific web.config, like so:

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="Namespace.For.MyExtensionClass" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 3):

This was added to ASP.NET MVC at version 5.2!

Property `Group` in SelectListItem allows you to specify a group for each item

`Html.DropDownList()` and `DropDownListFor()` now generate `optgroup` elements based on the groups included on the list of items.