# Error using Serge Zab's helper for optgroup dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, optgroup

I'm trying to work with the optgroup dropdown helper from Serge Zab that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851929/consuming-a-helper-code-for-optgroup-functionality-in-asp-net-mvc/8852941#8852941).

This is my category table:
[image]

As you can see I have a category and a category can also be categoryparent from a category. I want to have the parentcategorys as optgroup and the children as options of the optgroup. (Only the children can be selected)

In my ViewModel:

```
public short? CategoryId { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<ReUzze.Helpers.GroupedSelectListItem> GroupedTypeOptions { get; set; }
```

In my Controller:

```
[Authorize] // USER NEEDS TO BE AUTHORIZED
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.DropDownList = ReUzze.Helpers.EnumHelper.SelectListFor<Condition>();

    var model = new ReUzze.Models.EntityViewModel();
    PutTypeDropDownInto(model);
    return View(model);
}

[NonAction]
private void PutTypeDropDownInto(ReUzze.Models.EntityViewModel model)
{
    model.GroupedTypeOptions = this.UnitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Get()
         .OrderBy(t => t.ParentCategory.Name).ThenBy(t => t.Name)
         .Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
         {
             GroupKey = t.ParentId.ToString(),
             GroupName = t.ParentCategory.Name,
             Text = t.Name,
             Value = t.Id.ToString()
         }
     );
}
```

In my View:

```
@Html.DropDownGroupListFor(m => m.CategoryId, Model.GroupedTypeOptions,  "[Select a type]")
```

When I try to run this I always get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I get this error on this rule : `.OrderBy(t => t.ParentCategory.Name).ThenBy(t => t.Name)`

Can anybody help me find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error message suggests that either a `t` is `null` or a `t.ParentCategory` is `null`.

You can fix the error by simply checking for `null`s, but this may or may not give you the desired output, depending on whether you also want to include categories that don't have a parent.

```
model.GroupedTypeOptions = this.UnitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Get()
     .Where(t => t.ParentCategory != null)
     .OrderBy(t => t.ParentCategory.Name).ThenBy(t => t.Name)
     .Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
     {
         GroupKey = t.ParentId.ToString(),
         GroupName = t.ParentCategory.Name,
         Text = t.Name,
         Value = t.Id.ToString()
     });
```

I'm assuming your `CategoryRepository` can't return a `null` `t`, but if it can, you'd adapt the where to be:

```
.Where(t => t != null && t.ParentCategory != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that not all of your entities returned will have a ParentCategory.

It seems you should only be selecting the children and not the parents.

Try this:

```
model.GroupedTypeOptions = this.UnitOfWork.CategoryRepository.Get()
     .Where(t => t.ParentCategory != null)
     .OrderBy(t => t.ParentCategory.Name).ThenBy(t => t.Name)
     .Select(t => new GroupedSelectListItem
     {
         GroupKey = t.ParentId.ToString(),
         GroupName = t.ParentCategory.Name,
         Text = t.Name,
         Value = t.Id.ToString()
     }
 );
```