# How to make group by DropDown list in MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to Populate DropDown list of Country in MVC application. Where i have to make the Group as per the continent.. Any suggestion Help me alot Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look how to do it in [HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/MQDYd/)

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="G1">
    <option value="c1">One</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="G2">
    <option value="s1">Two</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

u can implement by your own like [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category.aspx)