# Hierarchical dropdownlist in MVC razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu, hierarchy

How can i create hierarchical custom dropdownlist in MVC razor as follow?Should i use helper method or static mvc string?Which one is true way?

```
Electronics
-Television
--Led Tv
--LCD Tv 
Computer
-Laptop
-Printer
--Laser
---HP
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support for optgroup in dropdownlist .NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed and answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc)

User Serge Zap has a very good answer involving some custom html helper extension methods.