# Create DropDownList using Iteration Loop

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, iteration

I will try my best to explain what I am looking for.

Let's say for argument's sake that I have a table in my database that has the properties `ID`, `Item`, `Category`...

the table is populated as so:

```
================================
|ID|    |Item       | Category |
================================
|  1    |  Batman   |   DC     |
|  2    |  Superman |   DC     |
|  3    |  Aquaman  |   DC     |
|  4    |  Spiderman|   Marvel |
|  5    |  Ironman  |   Marvel |
|  6    |  Thor     |   Marvel |
================================
```

Now, I want to create a dropdownlist with this information... but seperated by the category..

So it would look like this:

1. **DC**

   - -Batman
   - -Superman
   - -Aquaman
2. **Marvel**

   - -Spiderman
   - -Ironman
   - -Thor

Now it doesn't need to be as formatted as shown above but just a simple nested list with the emphasis on the `Category`

How would I iterate through the table and each time the `Category` changes to print that Category text once then print the `Item`'s that correspond with that `Category` underneath it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607188/support-for-optgroup-in-dropdownlist-net-mvc

Comment: How about something like this: http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category

Comment: Are you using asp.net-mvc? And if so which version?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes i am, version 5.2.3.0

Comment: Then you can just use one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) of `SelectList` that add the `dataGroupField` (or set the `Group` property of `SelectListItem`) and use `@HtmlDropDownListFor()` in your view

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much! I used the dataGroupField for SelectList. I didn't even see that overload. If you leave an answer I will mark it!

Comment: @StephenMuecke sounds good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC-5.2, you can use one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.) of `SelectList` that accepts `string dataGroupField` to group your options. For example, in the controller

```
model.OptionList = new SelectList(db.MyTable, "ID", "Item", "Category", null);
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyProperty, Model.OptionList)
```

Alternatively you can build an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and set the `Group` property, for example

```
List<SelectListItem> optionList = new List<SelectListItem>
var groups = db.MyTable.GroupBy(x => x.Category);
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    var optionGroup = new SelectListGroup() {Name = group.Key};
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        optionList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.ID.ToString(), Text = item.Item, Group = optionGroup });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to output your results as you initially provided, you could accomplish this by using a `GroupBy` call and then simply iterating through those groups (and subsequently the items within each group):

```
@foreach(var group in Model.GroupBy(g => g.Category))
{
     <ol>
        <li><b>@group.Key</b></li>
        <ul>
        @foreach(var item in group)
        {
            <li>- @item</li>
        }
        </ul>
     </ol>
}
```

This assumes that you already have the objects from your database within your Controller and are simply passing the collection of them into your View. Additionally, this example is performed within the View, which isn't ideal (you preferably want to handle this logic within the actual model itself).

As far as creating a DropDownList goes, you could really do the same if you wanted to preface each entry with its appropriate category :

```
<select id='Hero' name='Hero'>
@foreach(var hero in Model)
{
     <option value='hero.ID'>@hero.Category - @hero.Item</option>
}
</select>
```

Comment: You're also presuming he is using MVC and I don't see anything in the question to indicate that. Not saying he isn't, just saying it isn't really indicated by the question. The question doesn't even indicate a web application.

Comment: I only assumed this from the `model-view-controller` tag that was attached to the question.

Comment: Ok, good catch, I didn't even look at the tags, just read the question.

Comment: @Kevin  yes i am using MVC

Comment: why not use optgroup and nest the grouped options inside...

<select>
     <optgroup label="DC">
         <option> Superman</option>
     </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Marvel">
    </optgroup>
</select>

Comment: `<optgroup>` is a totally viable option for this. I just posted this to indicate a general idea that it wasn't limited to lists or anything else.

Comment: @Mike I need it to be dynamic to when something changes in the database

Comment: @RionWilliams Could you post an example of doing this in the model itself and not in the cshtml view?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid HTML structure shouldn't have an impact on what you do to generate the DDL. Optgroups will be dynamic if you setup your code to generate it as so.