# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.web.mvc.selectlistgroup'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Just so I don't have to write out another example to show what I am looking for.
Please reference this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411560/create-dropdownlist-using-iteration-loop?noredirect=1#comment60466746_36411560).

Using that example of a table in the database, I want to use the `Category` as the *subtitle* (for lack of better words) in a nested dropdownlist.

So here is what I have so far:

```
List<SelectListItem> lstAssignments = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using(var context = new databaseconnectionstring()/*fake connection string name*/)
        {
            List<table1> lstActivity = context.table1.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();

            foreach(table1 activity in lstActivity)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = activity.subcategory };
            }
```

I am receiving an error underneath the `Group = activity.subcategory`.

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.web.mvc.selectlistgroup'`

The `subcategory` property was purposefully created to distinguish the dropdownlist (same as `Category` in the referenced link)

How do I convert the `subcategory` to what it is asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you exactly what you need to do. The `Group` property is typed as `SelectListGroup` and you're passing it a string, hence the error. So, unwind that and you need merely create an instance of `SelectListGroup` utilizing your string. `SelectListGroup`, itself, has a `Name` property, so you should be able to do something like:

```
foreach(table1 activity in lstActivity)
{
    var group = new SelectListGroup { Name = activity.subcategory };
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = group };
}
```

Comment: I just figured this out and posted my answer.. haha dumb question. thanks though for your response.

Comment: How would i create this SelectListGroup before the foreach loop?  `SelectListGroup group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = context.table1./*stuck*/};`

Answer (score 1):

As the error mentions, you are trying to provide a String value to a [SelectListGroup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistgroup(v=vs.118).aspx) property.

You should have an initialization like below:

```
foreach(table1 activity in lstActivity)
{
    SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() 
        { 
           Text = activity.text, 
           Value = activity.ID.ToString(), 
           Group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = activity.subcategory }
        };
}
```

**[EDIT]**

An improvement would be declare `SelectListGroup`s before the foreach and assign them to items accordingly. This would create less instances.

Comment: I just figured this out.. haha dumb question.  thanks though for your response.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the actual `Group` property that you are attempting to set is expecting a [`SelectListGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistgroup(v=vs.118).aspx) object as opposed to a string, which your `activity.subcategory` is.

What you would need to do is actually create an instance of a `Group` and set the `Name` property of it to your category within your loop:

```
SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { 
                           Text = activity.text, 
                           Value = activity.ID.ToString(), 
                           Group = new SelectListGroup(){ Name = activity.subcategory }};
```

Comment: I just figured this out and posted my answer.. haha dumb question. thanks though for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry for this question. I just figured it out.

```
List<SelectListItem> lstAssignments = new List<SelectListItem>();

        using(var context = new fakeconnectionstring())
        {
            List<table1> lstActivity = context.table1.Where(x => x.deleted == false).ToList();

            foreach(table1 activity in lstActivity)
            {
                SelectListGroup lstGroupCategories = new SelectListGroup() { Name = activity.subcategory };
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = lstGroupCategories };
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<SelectListItem> CarregarDropDownList(Centro modeloSelected = null, string selecttext = null)
    {
        var centro = GetAtivos().GroupBy(x => x.Centro1).Select(group => group.First()).OrderBy(x => x.Centro1).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> lista = centro.Select(a => new SelectListItem() { Text = $"{a.Centro1}", Value = a.id_Centro.ToString(), Selected = (modeloSelected != null && modeloSelected.id_Centro == a.id_Centro) }).OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();
        //if (modeloSelected == null)
            lista.Insert(0, new SelectListItem() { Value = "", Text = selecttext ?? "-Todos-" });

        return lista;
    }
```